# Heat Equation with weird boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following problem of the heat equation:

$w_t - w_{xx}-4w_x+w=0; x\in(0,1),t>0$

$w(0,x)=e^x(\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x));x\in(0,1)$

$w(t,0)=w(t,1)=0;t>0$

My attempt:

Doing the change of variable $u(t,x)=w(t,x)e^{5t+2x}$

We have now the problem:

$u_t - u_{xx}=0; x\in(0,1),t>0$

$u(0,x)=e^{3x}(\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x));x\in(0,1)$

$u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0;t>0$

But doing with separation of variables $u(t,x)=V(t)X(x)$ I have to solve the ODE $X''+\lambda X=0 $ but then the initial condition of $X(0)=X(1)=0$ could not happen that $X(x)$ is the form of $c_n \cos(n \pi x)+b_n \sin(n\pi x)$ for any number n. I cant follow from here...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By $sen$ do you mean $\sin$?

Comment: Yes, sorry in Spain is sen :) I will edit it

Comment: For simplicity call the separation constant $-\lambda^2$ so you get the ODE $X'' + \lambda^2 X = 0$. You have solutions $c_n \cos(\lambda x) + b_n\sin(\lambda x)$. Imposing $X(0) = 0$ you get $c_n = 0$ and $X(1) = 0$ you get $\lambda = n\pi$ for some integer $n$ (as this are the zeros of $\sin(x)$). Now you have the full set of solutions and just need to match the initial condition to determine the $b_n$'s.

Comment: But then the solution $X(x)=b_n sin(n\pi x)$ does not match the condition of being equal to an exponential multiplied by sum of sines because $b_n$ are constant

Comment: You should go back and reread the basics of the method of separation of variables to make sure you fully understand the method. You don't just have *one* solution, you have a complete set of solutions $u_n(x,t)$ and any linear combination of these solutions is a solution. We have $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \sin(n\pi x) e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}$ and taking $t=0$ and using the initial condition allows you to determine the $b_n$'s (it's the Fourier $\sin$ coefficients of the initial condition; $\int_0^1 u(x,0)\sin(n\pi x){\rm d}x = b_n \int_0^1 \sin^2(n\pi x){\rm d}x$)

Comment: @energy no worries at all, that's information to me! In addition, note that in math mode, writing \sin produces $\sin$, and \cos produces $\cos$. You should write the functions in this way for better clairty.